# Limit method parameter value

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm building a library, and some of my methods have parameters that should be within a specific range. For example, in this method, `button` should be between 1 and 3 inclusive:

```
public static void pressMouse(int button){
    try{
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        if(button == 1){
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        }else if(button == 2){
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
        }else{
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Is there a way I can throw a compile-time error if the value isn't valid? E.g.

`TestLib.pressMouse(4);`

I could just throw an exception inside the method, but if theres a nicer way that would be cool.

Comment: Just a tip, since Elliott covered the main idea -- if you have a given set of values which you know at compile-time, that's a perfect use of enums. Yes, it can be awkward if you end up with a huge range of possible values, though. The type-safety is nice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as you have written it. However, one way to add that kind of compile time type checking is with an [`Enum` Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

```
public enum ButtonState {
  ONE, TWO, THREE;
  public void update(Robot robot) {
    if (robot == null) return;
    if (this == ONE) {
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    } else if (this == TWO) {
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    } else {
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
    }
  }
}

public static void pressMouse(ButtonState button) {
  try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    button.update(robot);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work! I'll fiddle around with it and see if it'll do what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot throw a compile-time error for things which can only be known at runtime; in this  particular case the values of your method's arguments are only known at runtime<sup>*</sup>. What you can do is establish method preconditions. Something like [`Preconditions`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) from Google Guava can do this for you:

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(button > 0 && button <= 3, "Button number must be between 1 and 3");
```

[Elliott Frisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24500713/263004) is another way you can accomplish this, however it still depends on the your `button` value coming from a known source. That is, whoever is supplying the `button` value must also return it as the `ButtonState` `enum`. If it's not, you will have to convert it over to `ButtonState` which gives rise to the same problem as before: you cannot guarantee that you will get a legal value (unless your source specifies that it will *always* return legal values).

<sup>*</sup> This is theoretically possible in certain languages. For example, in Ada you can specify a sub-type of integer that is only valid for certain ranges. The compiler can then emit a compile-type error if it turns out that this method is being called using an unconstrained integer-type. Java's type-system is not expressive enough to do this (at compile-time anyway). However, it is required that you are working with a value that is known to be within this range. If you are getting the value from a random source, there is no guarantee that it will be within the range you specify. Its value can only be known at runtime. However the compiler can at least warn you that this is a possibility. In Java, the best way to guard against this is just to use method preconditions. However, if you are working with a known-subset of values and you control both the source and destination of those values, then an `enum` is perfect for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'd prefer not to get into third party libraries just to accomplish this though. The information is helpful though.

Comment: @Nathan If you'd rather not get into third-party libraries, a simple `if` statement would suffice. :) Elliot's answer is pretty good and should work *as long as you have control over the source of the `button` value*, or if you know *for sure* (i.e., the method specifies it in its documentation) that it will only emit legal values.